# Switch with arrays method

Tags: java, switch-statement

This is my first experience with arrays and I'm confused with how to use arrays in this setting. I tried using switch but I am unsure about how it works using the different cases and such. Also unsure about what java knows or does not know when it comes to arrays using []. Can anybody let me know if i have the right idea or if i am completely off.

```
public class Sum3 {
    // TODO - write your code below this comment.
    // You will need to write a method that will take
    // an array of int, and will return the sum of
    // the first three elements.  NOTE THAT
    // THE ARRAY LENGTH MAY BE SMALLER THAN 3.
    // In the event that the array isn't long enough,
    // substitute 0s for the missing elements.
    // For example:
    // - if the array is empty you should return 0 (0 + 0 + 0 = 0),
    // - if the array contains only one element, you should
    //   return that element (element + 0 + 0 = element)
    // - if the array contains only two elements, you
    //   should return the sum of those two elements
    //   (first + second + 0 = first + second)
    // - if the array contains three or more elements,
    //   you should return the sum of the first three.
    //
    // You may be given an array which holds more than
    // three elements.  These extra elements (beyond three)
    // should be ignored.
    //
    // As a hint, switch may be useful here (though you
    // are not required to use it).
    //
    public static int array(int[] array) {
    switch (array) {
    case 0:
        return 0;
    case 1:
        return ([0]);
    case 2:
        return ([0]+[1]);
    case 3:
        return ([0]+[1]+[2]);

    // DO NOT MODIFY main!
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] array = new int[3];
        System.out.print("Enter first integer: ");
        array[0] = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter second integer: ");
        array[1] = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter third integer: ");
        array[2] = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Sum: " + sumUpToFirst3(array));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are better ways to implement it. As for using switch:

```
  switch (array.length) {
  case 1:
        return array[0] ; //instead of return ([0]);
        break;   //without it all other cases are evaluated
```

(p.s: If you can use streams:for a non-null array you can sum the the first up-to 3 elements can be calculated by `IntStream.of(array).limit(3).sum()` )

Answer (score 3):

It does not even look like the code you pasted would compile, but here is a simple implementation of `sumUpToFirst3` which I think should work:

```
public int sumUpToFirst3(int[] array) {
    if (array == null) {
        return 0;
    }

    int upperBound = array.length > 3 ? 3 : array.length;
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i=0; i < upperBound; ++i) {
        sum += array[i];
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Or you could do `for (int i=0; i < array.length && i<=3; ++i) `.

Comment: @AriaPahlavan `(i<=3)` should be `(i<3)`  (I prefer : `for (int i=0; i < Math.min(array.length, 3); ++i) `

Answer (score 1):

Your actual code makes no sense as you provide to the switch an array (that is not valid) and the cases expect a numeric value.

Valid expression for [the switch statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11) :

> The type of the Expression must be char, byte, short, int, Character,
>   Byte, Short, Integer, String, or an enum type (§8.9), or a
>   compile-time error occurs.

In your code comment, it refers to using a switch statement but it is really not required and it is not adapted either.

You could use the `switch` to test the length of the array and to compute the sum consequently but it is clearly not maintainable :

```
 switch (array.length) {
    case 0:
        return 0;
    case 1:
        return array[0];
    case 2:
        return array[0]+[1];
    case 3:
        return array[0]+[1]+[2];
}
```

A cleaner solution would be to use a `for` loop :

```
 int sum = 0;
 for (int value : array){
    sum+=value;
 }
```

Besides, you don't need to considerate the size as an array of `int` cannot have any `null` value. While the things would be different for an array of `Integer`.

Comment: ` return ([0]);` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't switch on an array. You **can** switch on `array.length`

```
switch (array.length) {
case 0: // <-- it's empty.
   return 0;
case 1: // <-- there's one element
   return array[0]; // <-- return the value of the first element
case 2:
   return array[0] + array[1];
default:
   return array[0] + array[1] + array[2];
}
```

Alternatively, if you're using Java 8+, you could use an `IntStream` - limit it to `3` elements (to match your requirements) and return the `sum`. Like,

```
public static int array(int[] array) {
    return IntStream.of(array).limit(3).sum();
}
```